# Checkout svn code with actual modified timestamp

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-plugins, visualsvn

I checkout the code from svn repository in Jenkins, the actual code is modified a month ago. But when I checkout code its showing modified date as current date. 
Is there any way to checkout code with actual modified timestamp in jenkins.?

I checked in google, we have option to enable "set date to last commit time" in tortoisesvn. But I dont have svn client in my jenkins machine.

Other option I got execute shell command " svn checkout --config-option config:miscellany:use-commit-times=yes" I cannot execute this command on behalf of my jenkins job.

Some help me to checkout code with actual timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has to be the one that you mentioned in your question: use the [`--config-option config:miscellany:use-commit-times=yes`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/confarea/) option. You should be able to add this config option to your commands or to the runtime config area without any problems.